# Histogram function - Python

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

Looking for someone who can explain this to me:

```
phase = mod(phase,Nper*2*pi)
cl_phase = arange(0,Nper*2*pi+step,step)
c,p = histogram(phase,cl_phase)

while 0 in c:
    step = step*2
    cl_phase = arange(0,Nper*2*pi+step,step)
    c,p = histogram(phase,cl_phase)
```

Where *phase* is the phase of a wave, *Nper* is the number of periods I'm analysing.

What I want to know is if some one can give me the name/link to an explanation of the histogram function..! Im not even sure from what package it comes from. Maybe numpy? Or maybe it even is a function that comes with python..! Super lost here..!

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`histogram()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) function is from `numpy` library. It doesn't come as a default function in Python.

You can use it by:

```
import numpy as np
np.histogram(phase,cl_phase)
```

In your code, it looks like you are using it as:

```
from numpy import histogram
histogram(phase,cl_phase)
```

`c,p = histogram(phase, cl_phase)` will give you two values as output. `c` will be the values of the histogram, and `p` will return the bin edges. You should take a look at the above docs for more info.